# numpy.ndarray.tofile with breakline after x number of entries?

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently passing data stored in a `numpy.ndarray` using the `numpy.ndarray.tofile` function which is built in `numpy.ndarray`.

Problem with this function is that is output all the data in on long line, making to hard to get great overview of the data.  Is it possible to make it output x entries an then make a new line and then continue or something like this?..

I could open a file, and convert the `ndarray` to a `string`,  but this will also cause some formatting issue, which is why i want to do it with `numpy.ndarray.tofile` function

I have a process next to writing to the file, which convert it to a different format. The conversion cant be performed as it cannot recognize when [ start.

I get the error message:

```
Expected "[", got "[-0.32252067" File position at start is 142665, currently 142678
```

But this is not the case with `tofile`

Comment: You can not with `numpy.ndarray.tofile`. But you can always open a file and write it as you like.

Comment: Doing that causes problems as such :

Comment: `Expected "[", got "[-0.32252067" File position at start is 142665, currently 142678`

Comment: Reshape the array, and write it with `np.savetxt`?

Comment: reshape it to what?

Comment: Show us some sample code.

Comment: Get on an interactive session and practice saving arrays of various shapes and types with `savetxt`.  It is well documented; plus the easiest way to learn it is to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a basic demonstration of writing a txt file

Make a nice 2d array:

```
In [1083]: arr=np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
In [1084]: arr
Out[1084]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Write with `tofile`:

```
In [1085]: arr.tofile('text.txt',sep=' ')

In [1086]: cat text.txt
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99In [1087]:
```

The result is a flat list, with separator, but no line breaks.  That's the normal action for `tofile`.  `tofile` is really meant to to write binary, with the text alternative for convenience.

For more control, use `savetxt`:

```
In [1091]: np.savetxt('text.txt', arr, delimiter=' ', fmt='%.2f')
In [1092]: cat text.txt
0.00 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00 7.00 8.00 9.00
10.00 11.00 12.00 13.00 14.00 15.00 16.00 17.00 18.00 19.00
20.00 21.00 22.00 23.00 24.00 25.00 26.00 27.00 28.00 29.00
30.00 31.00 32.00 33.00 34.00 35.00 36.00 37.00 38.00 39.00
40.00 41.00 42.00 43.00 44.00 45.00 46.00 47.00 48.00 49.00
50.00 51.00 52.00 53.00 54.00 55.00 56.00 57.00 58.00 59.00
60.00 61.00 62.00 63.00 64.00 65.00 66.00 67.00 68.00 69.00
70.00 71.00 72.00 73.00 74.00 75.00 76.00 77.00 78.00 79.00
80.00 81.00 82.00 83.00 84.00 85.00 86.00 87.00 88.00 89.00
90.00 91.00 92.00 93.00 94.00 95.00 96.00 97.00 98.00 99.00
```

This writes one 'row' of the array per line.  I can specify the format.  I can control the number columns by controlling the shape of the array.

I can add a header and footer if needed.  I could open a file as `wb`, and write other stuff to it along with using `savetxt`.